# Shuffling an arraylist based on special constraints?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, shuffle

I have an `ArrayList` of String. The length of this arraylist is dynamic (taken as input from the user). If user inputs `N`, size of the arraylist is `2N+2` The values that can be stored in this arraylist is restricted to 3 values (N blacks, N whites and 2 blanks). I need to shuffle this arraylist to set its initial value based on a seed value. I know

```
Collections.shuffle(yourList, new Random(somePredefinedSeed));
```

can be used to shuffle the Arraylist, but how do I do shuffle with the constraints I just specified.

Comment: What are the constraints? If they're just which values can go into the list, then shuffling doesn't violate those constraints and you can just used Collections.shuffle().

Comment: `Collections.shuffle` randomly shuffles the elements that are already in the array.  If you _start_ with N blacks, N whites, and 2 blanks, and call `Collections.shuffle`, you will always end up with N blacks, N whites, and 2 blanks.

Comment: Right now what I am doing is, I set this arraylist in a particular order and then apply Collections.shuffle() on it. I was checking whether there is any other way I could achieve this.

Comment: @phaedrusH `Collections.shuffle` is almost certainly the simplest and best way to achieve what you're going for.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Okay. Thanks.

Comment: How is shuffling related to the constraints on the contents of the list?

Comment: It does not have a direct impact. I wanted to check if there is some shuffling mechanism which would allow me to add the contents in the list and shuffle them in one go. For now what I did is, populate the Arraylist with the contents I need and used Collections.shuffle to shuffle them.